# rails + mongoid : limit fields using only keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, limit

I want to retrieve records with limited fields (i.e. omitting others). I searched a lot but query returns all fields with nil value which I dont want. e.g. for User model I want id, email only excluding name, age, etc.

thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Criteria#only` method for [selecting desired fields](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria#only-instance_method):

```
User.only(:_id, :email)
```

or `Criteria#exclude` for [excluding fields](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria#without-instance_method):

```
User.exclude(:password)
```

This is how Mongoid::Criteria looks for the first query:

```
#<Mongoid::Criteria
  selector: {}
  options:  {:fields=>{"_id" => 1, "email"=>1}}
  class:    User
  embedded: false>
```

so only `_id` and `email` are queried.

Comment: thanks for reply but this query also returns all other fields with null value which I dont want

Comment: also if I queried like `u = user.first`  and then tried u.only(:_id) then also it fires exception

Comment: @garry see `Mongoid::Criteria` it queries only required fields. You can't get rid of other fields (they are `nil`s though). And you cannot use `only` with a "user" (Mongoid::Document).

Comment: I got it ...I have converted it into json so now it removes all nil fields... Thanks for ur time

Comment: You are welcome @garry upvote and accept are appreciated :)

Comment: is there a way to exclude id from the result when using `only`? For some reason `User.only(:email)` returns '_id` too